# Looking for a regex to match a gmail plus address

Tags: regex

Im using this currently :

`/^(.*)\+(.*)@gmail.com/`

(I'm capturing the text before and after the plus sign in a group)

and it works in most cases such as 
`test+test@gmail.com`
but falls down if I try to match say 
`test+++test@gmail.com`

The repeated + signs seem to screw it up.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(.*?)\++(.*?)@gmail.com` should work.

Answer (score 1):

you need to escape the + sign : `/^(.+?)\++(.+?)@gmail.com/`

**EDIT** : your post was misformatted : your + is already escaped

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly detecting the +.  Use something like this: ^([^+]+)[+]+([^+]+)@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}[\+]{0,}[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,}@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [] with ^ (all the chars but...)
e.g.

```
echo 'aaa++++bbb@gmail.com' | perl -p -e 's/^([^\+]*)\+(.*)@gmail.com/$1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about validating the first portion of the address (prior to any '+') you could go with `/^([^+]+)(:?+[^+]*)*@gmail.com/` to just the first part.

You may want to do better validation on that to ensure that it is a "valid" account format, according to whatever rules are set forth by RFC.

*edit* -- asterisks were making a *bold* statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be simplified a touch:

IF you know the address you're looking for and want to match your address regardless of whether it has a 'plus' tag on it:

```
bignev(\+.*)*@gmail.com
```

If you only want the ones with the 'plus' tag:

```
bignev(\+.*)@gmail.com
```

If you have your own domain:

```
bignev(\+.*)*@everton.com
```

Or to answer the original post specifically:

```
.*(\+.*)@gmail.com
```